# How to add Filter in Spring MVC Javaconfig correctly

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters, spring-java-config

I'm a bit confused about adding Filters in Spring MVC with JavaConfig.

For example using the ResourceUrlEncodingFilter and the ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.

I've seen people doing this

```
  public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
  @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
       super.onStartup(servletContext);
               FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterRegistration = servletContext.addFilter("resourceUrlEncodingFilter",
            new ResourceUrlEncodingFilter());
       filterRegistration.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
       filterRegistration.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
       filterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");      
   }
  }
```

*(do i have to create a Filter registration for every single Filter?)*
or this

```
  @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
       return new Filter[] { new CharacterEncodingFilter() };
   }
```

or this

```
  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
       super.onStartup(servletContext);
      servletContext.addFilter("name", CharacterEncodingFilter.class)
              .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
  }
```

or

```
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   /* ... */       
   @Bean
   public ShallowEtagHeaderFilter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
    return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
   }
 }
```

or even this:

```
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
   /* ... */       
   @Bean
   public Filter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
    return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
   }
 }
```

*(seems not to work in my app)*

**So what is the best approach for adding Filters and keep code clean?**
*(What are the differences)*